# How to use Timefold webui (webjars) in a Node.js SPA/SSR framework?

Tags: timefold

Is this possible at the moment? I would like to use the Timefold webjars webui in Vue/Nuxt (for VRP specifically), however I can't find any resources in the web. Timefold also cannot be found in the webjars NPM / CDN repo.

The Timefold quickstarts import webjars via Maven (or maybe Gradle) and use vanilla JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `timefold-solver-webui` module is internal and we do not expect you to use it. It is a vehicle to share Timefold branding across the quickstarts and other places.

We have no intention to ever publish this webjar.
Do not use it.